# TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

When I try to connect to my web server always an error appears.

**[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOCTH.png) is my code:**

```
.controller('settingsCtrl', ['$scope','$stateParams',"$cordovaSQLite","$ionicLoading","$ionicPopup","$ionicPlatform","$cordovaPrinter","$cordovaNetwork",

function ($scope, $stateParams,$cordovaSQLite,$ionicLoading,$ionicPopup,$ionicPlatform,$rootScope,$cordovaPrinter,$cordovaNetwork,$http)
{
    $scope.Sync = function()
    {
        $ionicLoading.show();
        var query = "SELECT * FROM bus_transaction";
        var _bustransaction = [];

        $cordovaSQLite.execute(db,query,[]).then(function(res)
        {   
            if(res.rows.length > 0)
            {
                for(var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++)
                {
                    _bustransaction.push(res.rows.item(i));
                }       
            }
            console.log( JSON.stringify(_bustransaction) );

        }, function (err)
        {
           $scope.showAlert('Error',err);
           console.error(err);
        });

        var link = 'http://subdomain.domain.com/sync';
        $http.post(link, {update :JSON.stringify(_bustransaction)}).then(function (res)
        {
            console.log(res.data);
        });
    }
```

I injected `$http` in my controller.

**and this is the error:**

[image]

Comment: Please provide the error description

Comment: Little more info about the error will be helpful.

Comment: mmm it really looks that you don't inject correctly $http

Comment: can you post ALL your controller?

Comment: can you please paste the code of the entire controller?

Comment: Hi guys! i edited my post. sorry for messy text.

Comment: Code structure, spelling, ...